# How to edit a node module installed via yarn?

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, node-modules, yarnpkg

I'm using package called flowpoints. I made few changes in node modules of this package source according to my project need, I changed it in my local system. If I run yarn again, the changes which I made will be lost. How to update node modules? This should not affect the original package because I customized it only for my project need, it may not be helpful for others.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can't really do that in this way, because it's a third-party package. What you can do is to go to this package's GitHub and create this issue, if they accept it you can work on their repo and give a fix, which will then reflect when you do yarn install again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).